# select field, text field and foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know which way is the best to resolve my question :
I have a form in order to select people via a select field. If the name is missing in the select field, a text field is available to add directly the person's name.
- The form in `new.html.erb` is the format of the `new` action of the `Team` controller.
- The list of the people is extracted from the `People` model.

`def new

    @team   = Team.new

    @people = People.all

end`

I created an attribute in the `Team` model to store the `new_person` text field :

`class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :new_person

  ...

end`

Finally, here's an extract of my view :

`<%= f.select :person_id, @people.map { |p| [p.name, p.id] } %>

<%= f.text_field :new_person %>`

Obviously, I would like to save the new person in the table `Person` before saving the data from the form. As usual, the id are saved instead of the names

At this point, I've got two issues :
1/ The params array has the key `new_person` what doesn't have the table. So it is not possible to use the `Team.new(params[:team])` method. Does exist an easy solution to avoid this problem ?
2/ As I need the person_id, how can I get it when the name comes from the `new_person` field? In using the `before_filter` method ?

Thanks a lot,
Camille.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should consider using fields_for in your view within your form_for block. This will allow you to specify that the fields within the fields_for block are attributes of a different model, will generate the appropriately named input fields, and allow you to use params[:team] in your controller. See the [FormHelper documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) for more on this.

2) While you could do something in your controller to first check for a value in the new_person field, create the record, update the contents of params[:team] with the value of the newly created person and create the team, this feels a bit like a hack to me. Another possible solution which may be less fragile would be to use some JavaScript on the page that would render some kind of modal dialog for the user to create the new person, submit the new person to the person#create controller method, then refresh your drop down. It would probably not be terribly difficult to do this using a [jQuery UI modal form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) (very good example at that link to do what you need) with Rails remote form and unobtrusive JavaScript.

This is probably a more difficult solution to your second question than you are hoping for, but probably more useful in the long run.